# How to use Job DSL with Accurev SCM?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-job-dsl

I am using the following groovy script to create a Job DSL that uses Accurev as SCM.
Please let me know how should the correct script look like.

```
job('payer-server') {
  scm {
    accurev {
      /**What to insert here **/
    }
  }
  triggers {
    scm('H/15 * * * *')
  }
  steps {
    maven {
      goals('-e clean install')
      mavenOpts('-Xms256m')
      mavenOpts('-Xmx512m')
      properties skipTests: true
      mavenInstallation('Maven 3.3.3')
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no built-in support for Accurev SCM. Someone already filed a feature request as [JENKINS-22138](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22138).

But you can use a [Configure Block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) to generate the necessary config XML. There is an [example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block#configure-svn) for configuring Subversion, which can be adapted to Accurev.

```
job('example') {
    configure { project ->
        project.remove(project / scm) // remove the existing 'scm' element
        project / scm(class: 'hudson.plugins.accurev.AccurevSCM') {
            serverName('foo')
            // ...
        }
    }
    triggers {
        // ...
    }
    steps { 
        // ...
    }
}
```

Please leave a comment on the feature request to describe which options of Accurev SCM you need to configure initially.